# What kind of mixture(colloid) is a roux?

Tags: food-science, chemistry, roux

One of my coworkers had a curious question the other day: what kind of mixture or colloid is a roux? For example, whipped cream is a foam, mayonnaise is an emulsion, and gelatin is a gel.

I know part of creating a roux is the gelatinization of the starch in the flour, but does that make a roux a gel? Or is it something else?

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest that [a roux is a hydrocolloid](http://www.askmarxfoods.com/what-are-hydrocolloids/).

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @moscafj that roux falls in the category of hydrocolloids. But to further answer your question, I think it would be an emulsion.

From [Bonding With Food](https://bondingwithfood.wordpress.com/2010/03/15/in-class-experiment-emulsions-roux-mayonnaise-and-hollandaise/):

(The article title is: In Class Experiment – Emulsions (Roux, Mayonnaise, and Hollandaise))

> A roux is a mixture of heated flour and fat that is then used to thicken sauces, soups, and stews.  In a roux, the starch granules (from flour) are coated and separated by the fat from butter and dispersed throughout the mixture.